# PHP Dom Get Certain href Value Using strpos

Tags: php, dom

Could someone please tell me why this ain't working.

I'm trying to get a certain href and from a page by using php dom and that href -  `www.imdb.com/title/tt-some-id` contains the word `imdb` so in the example below i try to get the href by using php function `strpos` to look for the word `imdb` but it don't seen to work.

```
$page = 'www.someurl.com';
$data = array();
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($page);

$data['imdb_link'];

$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach ($links as $link) {
    $href = $link->getAttribute('href');
    if (false !== strpos($href,'imdb')) {
        $data['imdb_link'] = $href;
    } else {
        $data['imdb_link'] = '';
    }
}
```

And the links from the page

```
<a href="some-url.com"></a>
<a href="www.imdb.com/title/some-id"></a>
<a href="another-url.com"></a>
<a href="another-url.com"></a>
```

Could someone please tell me why it ain't working thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is actually working , but you are overwriting it..

As you can see your final `<a>` href does not contain the text **imdb** , so that will be overwritten by your previously found result by your `else` statement.

#### Well how to fix it ?

Just remove the `else` part from your code.

[Working Demo](https://eval.in/149597)

Comment: Thank you so much it was starting to give me a headache lol will vote up 4 mins

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 3):

You could move the logic to Xpath, too. The result will be an empty string of no matching element is found:

```
$page='<a href="some-url.com"></a>
<a href="www.imdb.com/title/some-id"></a>
<a href="another-url.com"></a>
<a href="another-url.com"></a>';
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$data['imdb_link'] = $xpath->evaluate(
  'string(//a[contains(@href, "imdb")]/@href)'
);
var_dump($data);
```

Output: https://eval.in/149602

```
array(1) {
  ["imdb_link"]=>
  string(26) "www.imdb.com/title/some-id"
}
```